# Finding if kernel is 32-bit or 64-bit on Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, 64-bit, cpu, 32bit-64bit

When I run uname -a, I get:

Linux  2.6.18-164.el5 #1 SMP Tue Aug 18 15:51:48 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

and I understand that x86_64 is supposed to imply 64-bit kernel, but why does this number appear 3 times? What does each instance signify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uname has separate commands to print "machine, processor and hardware platform" -- all of these are all the same in your case. The following outputs, respectively, may make it clear:

```
~$ uname -m # print machine
x86_64
~$ uname -p # print processor
x86_64
~$ uname -i # print hw platform
x86_64
```

Answer (score 3):

use uname -m command to display only  name of the kernel.

in your case

uname -m

x86_64

means 64-bit

Answer (score 2):

## uname -a

will give you all details about your system. It includes machine hardware name, processor type & hardware platform too.

So,

1. x86_64 is machine name.
2. x86_64 is processor type.
3. x86_64 is hardware platform.

Use:

## uname --help

to get more idea about its options.